# Lenient string matching with Mockito Mock

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have a test to verify the return of a null object if a string property of that object does not match a pre-determined value. My code is

```
import guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.model.Speciality;
import guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.repositories.SpecialtyRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SpecialtySDJpaServiceTest {

    @Mock
    SpecialtyRepository specialtyRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    SpecialtySDJpaService service;


    @Test
    void testSaveLambdaNoMatch() {

       // Given
       final String MATCH_ME = "MATCH_ME";
       Speciality speciality = new Speciality();
       speciality.setDescription("Not a match");

       Speciality savedSpeciality = new Speciality();
       savedSpeciality.setId(1L);

       // Need mock to only return on match MATCH_ME string
       given(specialtyRepository.save(argThat(argument -> argument.getDescription().equals(MATCH_ME)))).willReturn(savedSpeciality);

       // When
       Speciality returnedSpeciality = service.save(speciality);

       // Then
       assertNull(returnedSpeciality);

    }

   // Other tests...

}
```

This test fails with the message

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
- this invocation of 'save' method:
specialtyRepository.save(
guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.model.Speciality@19ae6bb
```

I believe the issue is that argThat() uses an exact matching scheme. I want to set the mock matching to lenient via

```
@Mock(lenient = true)
SpecialtyRepository specialtyRepository
```

But Intellij does not recognize the lenient parameter. I'm using JUnit 5 and Mockito 2.23.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Mock(lenient = true) was introduced in `Mockito` version `2.23.3`.

You either have to upgrade or use the [`other way`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mockito_lenient) to write this:

```java
lenient().when(specialtyRepository.save(argThat(argument -> argument.getDescription().equals(MATCH_ME)))).willReturn(savedSpeciality);
```

Comment: You can't use `lenient().given().willReturn()`. Lenient is only available for non-BDD syntax. `lenient().when().thenReturn()`

Comment: @mend: You are correct, I adjusted the answer. Even now it seems the related [feature request](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1597) has not made it into any version.